# Mutating a variable in the body of a closure

Tags: rust, closures

I'm writing a bunch of assertions that all involve popping a value from a list.

Coming from a Scala background, I naturally did this:

```
let mut list = List::new();
let assert_pop = |expected| assert_eq!(list.pop(), expected);
```

So that I could just write `assert_pop(None)` or `assert_pop(Some(3))` instead of having to write `assert_eq!(list.pop(), None)` or `assert_eq!(list.pop(), Some(3))` every time.

Of course the borrow checker doesn't like this one bit because the closure essentially needs to borrow the value for an undisclosed amount of time, while the rest of my code goes around mutating, thus violating the rule of *"no aliasing if you're mutating"*.

The question is: is there a way to get around this? Do I have to write a macro, or is there a funky memory-safe way I can get around this?

**Note** that I know that I can just define the closure like this:

```
let_assert_pop = |lst: &mut List, expected| assert_eq!(lst.pop(), expected);
```

But that would be less *DRY*, as I'd have to pass in a `&mut list` as the first argument at every call.

Answer (score 2):

They key is to **define the closure as mut**, since it needs a mutable reference.

This works:

```
let mut v = vec![1, 2];
let mut assert_pop = |expected| assert_eq!(v.pop(), expected);

assert_pop(Some(2));
assert_pop(Some(1));
assert_pop(None);
```

Note that the the `pop` closure borrows mutably, so you if you want to use  the list afterwards, you have to scope it:

```
let mut v = vec![1,2];
{
    let mut assert_pop = |expected| assert_eq!(v.pop(), expected);
    assert_pop(Some(2));
    v.push(33); // ERROR: v is borrowed mutably...
}
v.push(33); // Works now, since pop is out of scope.
```

Comment: Having to scope it isn't ideal, (and I know didn't make this clear) because the code has interleaved pushes and asserts. I.e. it pushes some values, then asserts via popping if it holds true, then pushes more values, etc.

Comment: I would generally not do what you described. It sounds quite confusing for a reader. What's so bad about assert_eq!(list.pop(), Some(3)); ?

Comment: If you really, really want to do this, you can write a macro, which is equally confusing though, imo: macro_rules! assert_pop { ($expected:expr) => { assert_eq!(v.pop(), $expected); } }

Comment: yeah I suppose this is a case for brevity against clarity, which isn't always the best

Comment: If you do use a macro, note that you have to declare the macro inline inside the function AFTER declaring the list variable, due to macro hygiene.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of directly answering your question (which is [well-enough answered already](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41453709/155423)), I'll instead address your other points:

- just write `assert_pop(None)` or `assert_pop(Some(3))`
- a memory-safe way solution
- don't pass in a `&mut list`

To solve all that, don't use a closure, just make a new type:

```
type List<T> = Vec<T>;

struct Thing<T>(List<T>);

impl<T> Thing<T> {
    fn assert_pop(&mut self, expected: Option<T>) 
        where T: PartialEq + std::fmt::Debug,
    {
        assert_eq!(self.0.pop(), expected);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let list = List::new();
    let mut list = Thing(list);

    list.0.push(1);
    list.assert_pop(Some(1));
    list.assert_pop(None);

    // Take it back if we need to
    let _list = list.0;
}
```